# Swift: Adding negative numbers

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, negative-number

I've got a pretty simple problem with adding negative numbers, but Apple Documentation doesn't really cover this.

SwiftUI Code:

```
Text(String(-50 + 5))
```

This throws the error, `Compiling failed: Ambiguous use of operator '-'`. However, `Text(String(-50))` doesn't throw any errors.

I've tried casting -50 as an Int and wrapping it in parentheses. Also, if I assign `-50 + 5` to a variable, and then use the variable in the Text(), it works fine. How can I get this to display -45, and what's causing the error?

**Note**: Using XCode 13.2.1 on macOS Monterey

**EDIT:** People are asking for a screenshot, as it seems the issue isn't occurring for everyone. Here's the issue in a brand new project.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That code compiles and runs fine for me with Xcode 13.1 -- which version are you using?

Comment: XCode 13.2.1... Just double checked and I get the same error still

Comment: What happens if you do `Text(String(0 - 50 + 5))`?

Comment: But you have to explain why no one else sees this. Show more code, or even post a project that demonstrates.

Comment: The code works for me, using macos 12.2 Beta and Xcode 13.2 to compile, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.

Comment: I added a screenshot... I replicated this in a completely empty project

Comment: Does it only fail in the preview or does it also fail if you compile for the simulator?

Comment: @jnpdx, can you make that an answer? It fixes the issue! Still unsure why it's happening, though... Also, it fails to build for the simulator as well.

Comment: Which comment of mine works? The `0 - 50 + 5`? I'm hesitant to post an answer because I don't have an explanation either and it doesn't seem replicable by others yet.

Comment: Fair. The 0 - 50 + 5 works for me, thanks so much for the help! let me know if you find out what's happening

Comment: Why would you need to do some calculation like this while initializing a String?

Comment: Seems Xcode is a bit `dumb`resolving the type of 50 cases the `- operator`is defined in Int, Float, Double ...

try `Text(-Int(50) + 5)` for the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Canvas diagnostics:

```
Swift.Float16:3:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float16) -> Float16
                              ^
Swift.Float:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float) -> Float
                              ^
Swift.Double:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Double) -> Double
                              ^
Swift.Float80:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float80) -> Float80
```

and tell Xcode which type you wanna use:

e.g.

```swift
Text(String(-Int(50) + 5))
```

or

```swift
Text(String(-50.0 + 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

See the error, it probably code can't reconize -50 to int.

```
Swift.Float16:3:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float16) -> Float16
                              ^
Swift.Float:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float) -> Float
                              ^
Swift.Double:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Double) -> Double
                              ^
Swift.Float80:2:31: note: found this candidate
    prefix public static func - (x: Float80) -> Float80
```

So I test for some example like this is wrok.

```
let a =  -Int(50) + 3
let b =  -50.0 + 3
let c:Int = -50 + 3

Text(String(-Int(50) + 3))
Text(String(a))
Text(String(b))
Text(String(c))
```